# Qt how to print formatedtext on dot matrix printer?

Tags: qt, printing

I need to print (with Qt) formated text on dot matrix printer. Problem is that QPrinter class is generating graphic mode text only. 
How to print formated text on dot matrix printer? Do you know any c++ lib that handle this issue?

Comment: Besides that I do not know where to get a dot matrix printer these days ;-) : Should this not be handled by the printer driver (Windows/CUPS)? Have you tried to use QPrinter as described at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html? Can you be more specific about your environment (OS, printer type, etc.)? Is your printer supported by your OS at all (means, can you print to your printer from other applications?)

Comment: A lot companies are using dot matrix printers because it's cheaper when you have to print a lot documents (invoices). Even when your document contains only text, QPrinter is generating graphic document and send it to printer. I need to find a way to send formated text directly to device.